# How can I solve list indices error in python? I can not understand it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
  my_goods= [
  {"name": "shirt", "cost_price": 32.67, "sell_price": 45.00, "inventory": 1200},
  {"name": "ball", "cost_price": 225.89, "sell_price": 550.00, "inventory": 100},
  {"name": "dumbbell", "cost_price": 2.77, "sell_price": 7.95, "inventory": 8500}
          ]

  print(my_goods["name"])
```

this is error:
print(my_goods["name"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: What do you expect `my_goods["name"]` to evaluate to?

Comment: `my_goods` is a list. `my_goods["name"]` attempts to index into it with a string. This doesn't make sense because lists are indexed with _integers_ (or slices), not strings.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A nested dictionary? `my_goods[i]["name"]` works for any integer `i` because it is a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `my_goods` is a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) of [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict). The list don't allow to use Keys to access the items, you have to use an integer. The dictionary allows you to access it with a Key and get the value assigned to that key.

```py
    print(type(my_goods))     # Returns <class 'list'>
    print(type(my_goods[0]))  # Returns <class 'dict'>
```

If you want to get the value of `name` you have to do it like this:

```py
    print(my_goods[0]["name"])   # Return shirt
```

You can iterate over the list like this:

```py
for x in my_goods:
    print(x['name'])
#OUTPUT 1: shirt
#OUTPUT 2: ball
#OUTPUT 3: dumbbell
```

In this case you are printing the Key value for each dictionary.

Comment: Hi @Mahdi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

my_goods is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary.

Try `print(my_goods[0]["name"])` to print 'shirt', for example. By looping over the list indices, you can print the values corresponding to the 'name' key in all dictionaries.